# How locate a file's location and CD to the directory?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm making a batch that edits a document, but in order to edit, it need's to CD it its location. The problem I'm having is that in order to make it portable, I need the command to be able to locate the file's location.

I've tried:

```
 CD C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype\John

 CD C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype\%foldername%\config.xml
```

Any way to get to the location with the config.xml?

Comment: You probably need `CD "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype\John"` (always try to surround paths with double quotes). With a little more info on what error message you get or what happens wrong we might be able to help you more.

Comment: The folder that I need to CD to is the one that contains the config.xml However, this folder name changes for every user.

Comment: What happens when you use what you've tried : `CD C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype\John`?

Comment: Pretty sure you're looking for the `where` command, but it's super slow on machines with large hard drives.

Comment: @J.Baoby - he's saying that `John` can be anything (and also that it might not be in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype`, I think) but he still needs to find the location of config.xml

Comment: @J.Baoby That's the folder I need the batch to CD too however the name (username) of the directory is different for other PC owners. I need a way to search for the file and CD to its location.

Comment: @SomethingDark You know a fix? and PS the location of the file will always be in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype\`

Comment: Will there be more than one folder in that directory?

Comment: @SomthingDark Yes.

Comment: Then how do you know which config.xml file to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
FOR /D %%G IN ("%APPDATA%\skype\*") DO IF EXIST "%%~fG\config.xml" (
    set correctDir=%%G
    goto :foundFile
)
echo File config.xml not found
goto :eof

:foundFile
cd "%correctDir%"
```

[`FOR /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) iterates over all directories using the `%%G` variable. `%%~fG` expands to the full path to the directorie in %%G.
[`IF EXIST`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) checks if a file exists.
`goto :eof` exits the script

**EDIT**: As @Compo pointed out: for portability reasons it is better to use the OS built-in environment variable `%APPDATA%` instead of `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming`.

Comment: "File config.xml not found" Does this command check all directorys? Lets say there are more then one folder within `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype`

Comment: Is it in a subfolder of skype or in a subfolder of a subfolder of the skype folder?

Comment: The location is `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype\John`

Comment: I tried putting a copy of `config.xml` into `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\skype` . The command does detect the file and cd's. However it's not finding the file in the John directory.

Comment: My apologies I had forgotten to copy the last part of the path. I've edited my answer.  It should be fixed now

Comment: The code works. You sir are a true legend. Really appreciate it!

Comment: My pleasure! Sorry for the misunderstandings.

Comment: ...just to mention, as it seems to have been compltely missed in this entire thread, the location should just be, `%AppData%\skype`. At worst even `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\skype` is an improvement.

Comment: @JohnKens I've edited the answer according to Compo's comment.